# Flutter: Full bottom button with safe area

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I faced with this problem: I found the only way to do so that the background of the button was in full height when using safearea on iPhone 11. But now the button is pressed partially podskajet. Please how to make the entire blue area pressed as a button. Thank you all for your answers.
I add a screenshot and a piece of code as it is implemented now.

[image]

```
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: SafeArea(
          left: false,
          right: false,
          child: Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 0,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Add", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: you want to make the blue area pressable ?

Comment: I want the entire blue area to be clickable, like a single button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by changing the color of this Container.

```
   Container(
    color: Colors.red,
```

Or you can use `Debug Paint` using the [inspector](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector). And then you will realize that some area is not in the button. This is the reason why onTap is not working.

After that time you can use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) easily with wrapping all your Container.

```
  InkWell(
      onTap: () {
       // Here is your onTap function
      },
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: SafeArea(
          left: false,
          right: false,
          child: Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              // In fact, you don't need a button anymore.
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 0,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Add", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
```

Comment: I want the entire blue area to be clickable, like a single button